# Lifetime issues in rust: borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: multithreading, rust, lifetime

I have reproduced my problem in the short code below.

*Problem*: The `inner thread` uses reference of variable `v` from the `outer thread`. The rust compiler throws an error because "technically" the `outer thread` could terminate before the `inner thread` and hence `inner thread` could loose access to variable `v`. However in the code below that clearly cannot happen.

*Question*: How shall I change this code so that it complies while maintaining the same functionality?

```
fn main() { //outer thread
    let v = vec![0, 1];
    let test = Test { v: &v }; //inner_thread
    std::thread::spawn(move || test.print());
    loop {
        // this thread will never die because it will never leave this loop
    }
}

pub struct Test<'a> {
    v: &'a Vec<u32>,
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.v);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:3:26
  |
3 |     let test = Test { v: &v }; //inner_thread
  |                          ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
4 |     std::thread::spawn(move || test.print());
  |     ---------------------------------------- argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
...
8 | }
  | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want test to hold a reference and not move v ? The real solution depends on your real problem, which isn't shown here. The solution might be moving, using static, using crossbeam's scope, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution would be to have Test own the vector instead of just have a reference.

But if you really need to borrow the value in the thread (probably because you want to use it after end of execution), then you may use [crossbeam's scope](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.2/crossbeam/fn.scope.html):

```
let v = vec![0, 1];
let test = Test { v: &v }; //inner_thread
crossbeam::thread::scope(|scope| {
    scope.spawn(|_| test.print());
}).unwrap();
```