# Mapping a 2d slice in parallel

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I'm trying to map a 2d slice in parallel.
I'm doing this by assigning every child slice to one thread. So, if the slice is 10x10, 10 threads will be spawned.

I'm doing this by creating a Mutex for each child slice. The problem is that I'm getting an error for the parent slice:

```rs
error[E0759]: `collection` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> src\lib.rs:151:34
    |
145 |     fn gen_map_par<T: Send + Sync, F: Fn(f32, &mut T) + Send + Sync + 'static>(&self, collection: &[&[T]], predicate: F) {
    |                                                                                                   ------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
151 |         for (x, i) in collection.iter().enumerate() {
    |                                  ^^^^ ...is captured here...
...
155 |             let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                          ------------- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0759`.
```

The error shows that collection is being captured. Here is the associated code.

```rs
fn gen_map_par<T: Send + Sync, F: Fn(f32, &mut T) + Send + Sync + 'static>(
    &self,
    collection: &[&[T]],
    predicate: F,
) {
    let perm = Arc::new(self.perm);
    let closure = Arc::new(predicate);
    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for (x, i) in collection.iter().enumerate() {
        // iterating through parent slice
        let p = Arc::clone(&perm);
        let c = Arc::clone(&closure);
        let s = Arc::new(Mutex::new(*i)); // mutex created for one entire child slice
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            // spawning the thread
            let slice = s.lock().unwrap();
            // collection gets moved into the thread for some reason.
            for (y, e) in slice.iter().enumerate() {
                let v = Simplex::convert_range(
                    max_2d,
                    min_2d,
                    1.0,
                    -1.0,
                    generate2d(x as f32, y as f32, &p),
                );
                (c)(v, &mut slice[y]);
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

I've tried wrapping the 'collection' in an arc/mutex, but neither of these works. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. The only solution I've found is to make `collection` static, but this would require the user to input a static variable, which I do not want to require.

Comment: This is not really fully a duplicate because it also contains the question about why wrapping a reference in an Arc will not work, but you will probably find your answer on any of these: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread/32751956#32751956) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214992/lifetime-issues-in-rust-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough/57215484#57215484) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182117/change-elements-in-vector-using-multithreading-in-rust/71182237).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750829/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-stack-variable-to-a-thread)

Comment: @Caesar I do think this is a duplicate since the OP does not show the code that tries to wrap in `Arc`, nor they ask why it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

After trying crossbeam::scope(), doing some research, and reading @Ceasars' suggestions, I have concluded that using a closure inside of a thread like this is either impossible or very difficult to do because the data has to  be moved into the closure as a mutable reference, something the compiler will not allow as far as I can tell. Moving on to another project.

Thanks to everybody who responded, reading your suggestions helped me understand parallelism in rust better.

Comment: The compiler does allow this kind of thing if you tread carefully. `iter_mut` (or `split_mut` on slices) together with scoped threads.